# How to allow windows to install a program it thinks is a virus?

Tags: windows, anti-virus

We have a web application used inside our organization by some staff members.  It sends messages to a local "launcher" application via http requests sent by javascript.  It works perfectly, except that for some staff members the windows anti-virus thinks the launcher is a virus and won't let us install it.

This causes much distress for our staff, especially since they work from home using their own laptops and we have to persuade them that windows is lying and that they should indeed download the executable, and run it.

I imagine that because it is a program that launches programs locally based on messages it receives from HTTP (and is therefore a webserver), this raises red flags.

How can we smooth the process and allow it to be installed?

Comment: It would help to say which antivirus is causing the issues.

Comment: I took the post to mean Windows Defender but maybe not.  Can you whitelist the program to allow it to install?

Comment: Is this a domain environment?

Comment: ok so first off, windows will never say "this is a virus". what Precisely does it say in exact words? a picture may help. if you have run afoul of smart app screen, its not actually saying it thinks its a virus its just saying that it hasn't been authoritively categorized. the solution in that case is to have the developer sign the application

Comment: It's unclear whether or not these are personal or enterprise computers. Knowing this is a key part of getting you the right answer.

Comment: personal computers.  windows defender deletes the file immediately after download and claims it deleted a virus.